# Raspberry Pi - Call Blocker

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-2

This may not be the place for this post, and if that is the case please advise where to ask this question.

I am trying to make my home phone number require that ANYONE who calls it must enter a numeric code, defined by me, before their call will be connected and cause my phone to ring. This is because no matter how many times I switch my phone number, someone has always had it previously, and I get their collections/etc calls.

I have seen this... https://murphy101blog.wordpress.com/2013/11/03/raspberry-pi-telephone-number-blocker/ using a Raspberry Pi, but I do not want to block based on a blacklist, I want to block ALL and require they enter a numeric code before they get through.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can go about this? From all the searching I've done I can only seem to find devices that block based on a blacklist, devices that prompt the caller to speak their name, etc before the call is connected.

Any suggestions on what I can use or if there are any devices in existence already, what they are called?

thank you!

**UPDATE**

After searching some more, I've found that the open-source software framework Asterisk is now available for Raspberry Pi http://www.raspberry-asterisk.org/.  I'm wondering, could this be the answer to this question?

I also found this script which SEEMS to do what I want.
https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Authenticate+Users+by+Caller+ID+or+PIN+-+password

Comment: Modems generally respond to [Hayes commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set), I'd presume those include a way to deal with number-tones but I can't say for sure.  Probably the best place to ask is S.O.; they [have a tag for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/at-command).

Comment: @goldilocks - lol I did ask on S.O. and they referred me here.

Comment: As in, **you already asked a specific question about AT commands**? I'm [not seeing that](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1268048/phil) but perhaps you deleted the question.  I'm fine with leaving this open here, but if you want to move forward, read up on the Hayes stuff and/or come up with an appropriate question for S.O. ;)